# PHP Date reading problem, I got a Number not a Date

Tags: php, excel, date

I want to read dates from an Excel File, but when I print
the dates to the screen I can only see one number instead Of 
the date, why?

Excel file:

[image: Excel file]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: show us the relevant code so we can help you on your way - read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's most likely because of the format of the file that is read. You might want to try a different file extension, such as csv.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. Without you showing us what you did in the first place, we can hardly tell you what you might have done wrong.

Comment: I'm Just use a 'phpoffice' github repo for the reading datas, from the excel, and only print_r($data) to the screen. But now unless to share my code with you, beacuse the promlem are solved, by the second comments. I save the excel to another format, (csv) and I got a date instead of one number. Thanks For Helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel treats dates as numbers, with the number representing the number of days after December 31 1899. So day 1 is January 1 1900, and day 43102 is January 3 2018. But wait... your data says January 2 2018! It turns out that Microsoft thinks that 1900 was a leap year and so day 60 is February 29 1900 when in the real world it was actually March 1. Anyway, what that means is that for dates after February 28 1900, you need to subtract one from the day number to get the correct date. So, to convert an Excel day number to a date in PHP, you use the following code:

```
$dayval = 43102;    // you would read from your file here
$date = new DateTime('1899-12-31');
$date->modify("+$dayval day -1 day");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

```
2018-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this formula to change from Excel date to Unix date, then you can use "gmdate" to get the real date in PHP:
 `UNIX_DATE = (EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400` 
and to convert from Unix date to Excel date, use this formula:
`EXCEL_DATE = 25569 + (UNIX_DATE / 86400)`
After putting this formula into a variable, you can get the real date in PHP using this example:
`$UNIX_DATE = ($EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400;
echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", $UNIX_DATE);`

The 86400 is number of seconds in a day = 24 * 60 * 60. The 25569 is the number of days from Jan 1, 1900 to Jan 1, 1970. Excel base date is Jan 1, 1900 and Unix is Jan 1, 1970. UNIX date values are in seconds from Jan 1, 1970 (midnight Dec 31, 1969). So to convert from excel you must subtract the number of days and then convert to seconds