# phpExcel given timestamp instead of actual date in excel sheet

Tags: php, laravel, date, timestamp, phpexcel

I used `PhpExcel` to read data from excel sheet, all data are proper, but date data are given as timestamp instead of actual date in sheet and also percent value convert as a point value

I used below code for phpExcel

```
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
```

The actual date is `13-10-2019` in sheet and given when reading `43751` and percent value is `20%` and given `0.2`

Comment: You might find this helpful to deal with the date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645764/php-date-reading-problem-i-got-a-number-not-a-date/52646281#52646281

Comment: Thanks its helpful link and solved my problem @Nick

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to upvote if you did find it useful! ;-)