# Incorrect date value when loading xlsx file to table using pymysql and xlrd

Tags: python, mysql, date, xlrd, pymysql

(Very) beginner python user here. I'm trying to load an xlsx file into a MySQL table using xlrd and pymysql python libraries and I'm getting an error:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1292, "Incorrect date value: '43500' for column 'invoice_date' at row 1")

The datatype for `invoice_date` for my table is `DATE`. The format for this field on my xlsx file is also Date. Things work fine if I change the table datatype to varchar, but I'd prefer to have the data load into my table as a date instead of converting after the fact. Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error? It appears that xlrd or pymysql is reading **'2/4/2019'** in my xlxs file as **'43500'** and mysql is rejecting it due to a datatype mismatch.

```
import xlrd
import pymysql as MySQLdb

# Open workbook and define first sheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook("2019_Complete.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# MySQL connection
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user="root",passwd="password", db="vendor")

# Get cursor, which is used to traverse the databse, line by line
cursor = database.cursor()

# INSERT INTO SQL query
query = """insert into table values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

# Create a For loop to iterate through each row in the XLS file, starting at row 2 to skip the headers
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    lp = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    pallet_lp = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    bol = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    invoice_date = sheet.cell(r,3).value
    date_received = sheet.cell(r,4).value
    date_repaired = sheet.cell(r,5).value
    time_in_repair = sheet.cell(r,6).value
    date_shipped = sheet.cell(r,7).value
    serial_number = sheet.cell(r,8).value
    upc = sheet.cell(r,9).value
    product_type = sheet.cell(r,10).value
    product_description = sheet.cell(r,11).value
    repair_code = sheet.cell(r,12).value
    condition = sheet.cell(r,13).value
    repair_cost = sheet.cell(r,14).value
    parts_cost = sheet.cell(r,15).value
    total_cost = sheet.cell(r,16).value
    repair_notes = sheet.cell(r,17).value
    repair_cap = sheet.cell(r,18).value
    complaint = sheet.cell(r,19).value
    delta = sheet.cell(r,20).value

    # Assign values from each row
    values = (lp, pallet_lp, bol, invoice_date, date_received, date_repaired, time_in_repair, date_shipped, serial_number, upc, product_type, product_description, repair_code, condition, repair_cost, parts_cost, total_cost, repair_notes, repair_cap, complaint, delta)

    # Execute sql Query
    cursor.execute(query, values)

# Close the cursor
cursor.close()

# Commit the transaction
database.commit()

# Close the database connection
database.close()

# Print results
print ("")
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print ("I just imported " + columns + " columns and " + rows + " rows to MySQL!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645764/php-date-reading-problem-i-got-a-number-not-a-date/52646281#52646281) for a more detailed explanation, but basically Excel treats dates as a number relative to 1899-12-31, and so to convert your date value to an actual date you need to convert that number into an ISO format date which MySQL will accept. You can do that using [`date.fromordinal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal) and [`date.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat). For example:

```
dval = 43500
d = date.fromordinal(dval + 693594)
print(d.isoformat())
```

Output:

```
2019-02-04
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up needing to do a bit of light formatting but i ended up with something like this for each date field.

`idf = date.fromordinal(int(invoice_date + 693594))

 invoice_date_fixed = idf.isoformat()`