# Importing Dates from Excel to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: python, sql, excel

Hope everyone is well and staying safe.

I'm  uploading an Excel file to SQL using Python. I have three fields: CarNumber nvarchar(50), Status nvarchar(50), and DisassemblyStart date.

I'm having an issue importing the DisassemblyStart field dates. The connection and transaction using Python are succesful.

However I get zeroes all over, even though the Excel file is populated with dates. I've tried switching to nvarchar(50), date, and datetime to see if I can least get a string and nothing. I saved the Excel file as CSV and TXT and tried uploading it and still got zeroes. I added 0.001 to every date in Excel (as to add an artificial time) in case that would make it clic but nothing happened. Still zeroes. I sure there's a major oversight from being too much in the weeds. I need help.

The Excel file has the three field columns.

This is the Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Import CSV
data = pd.read_csv (r'PATH_TO_CSV\\\XXX.csv')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['CarNumber','Status','DisassemblyStart'])
df = df.fillna(value=0)


# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVERNAME,PORT ;Database=DATABASENAME;Uid=USER;Pwd=PW;")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table
cursor.execute ('DROP TABLE OPS.dbo.TABLE')

cursor.execute ('CREATE TABLE OPS.dbo.TABLE (CarNumber nvarchar(50),Status nvarchar(50), DisassemblyStart date)')

# Insert READ_CSV INTO TABLE 
for row in df.itertuples():

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO OPS.dbo.TABLE (CarNumber,Status,DisassemblyStart) VALUES (?,?,Convert(datetime,?,23))',row.CarNumber,row.Status,row.DisassemblyStart)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Thank you and be safe,

David

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308645/incorrect-date-value-when-loading-xlsx-file-to-table-using-pymysql-and-xlrd/60310264#60310264